# How to select some black color cells in a chess board such that each white cell has exactly 1 adjacent selected black cell?

Tags: graph-theory, chessboard

Given a chess board of size $n$ x $n$, where $n$ is an even number. How do i prove that for any given even number n, there exists a way to select some of the black cells of the chess board such that each of the white cells in the chess board has exactly 1 selected black square adjacent to it.
 Two cells are adjacent if they share an edge.

I tried looking for some pattern in the way black squares are selected and then tried to generalize it. But i failed to do so.

I have another approach but cant fully prove why this will work.

The approach is to traverse the chess board in a row major way (i.e go to the first row and check all cells from left to right, then go to the second row and check all the cells from left to right and so on). And while doing this if we reach a black square such that all the adjacent white cells to this black cell has 0 selected black cells adjacent to them, then we select this black square. 
 This approach works but i cant prove why its correct?

Comment: So, cells that share a *diagonal point* are not considered adjacent?

Comment: My first attempt, which could easily fail, would be to try to prove the assertion for $n=2$ and then $n=4$.  Then, I would try to look for a pattern in these special case proofs, and try to generalize the proof to any even number $n$.

Comment: @user2661923 Since the squares diagonally adjacent to a white square are all white, I don't see how the distinction between these types of adjacency makes any difference in the answer.

Comment: @DavidK Good point, my oversight.

Comment: My first thought is that there are two sub-problems: how to choose squares in the middle of the board (which is most of the squares, for large $n$) and how to finish the edges of the board. Small $n$ such as $n=2$ or $n=4$ will be practically all edges, so I think you need to go a bit larger to find a pattern that will continue to work for all $n$ if that's the approach. But small(ish) $n$ would be my approach too, just keep working upward until a pattern emerges (or until you despair of finding a pattern and decide to try some other way).

Comment: @DavidK I have updated the question please check it

Comment: @user2661923 I have updated the question please check it

Comment: Closely related to tiling with 5-piece "plus" shaped pieces and single black tiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose w.l.o.g. that the top left square is black. Divide the board into $2\times 2$ regions. These regions will be three kinds: $A$, $B$, or unmarked. In each $A$ region, we will mark the top left black square. In each $B$ region, we will mark the bottom right black square.

First we assign the regions along the top-right/bottom-left diagonal. These are all $A$ when $n\equiv 2\pmod4$, and the diagonal immediately below it is all $B$. On the other hand, if $n$ is a multiple of $4$, then we make that diagonal all $B$, with the diagonal immediately above it all $A$.

Moving out along parallel diagonals, above each $A$ diagonal is a blank one, followed by another $A$ diagonal. Below each $B$ diagonal is a blank one, followed (if there's still room) by another $B$ diagonal.

To verify that this works, we need to check white squares in the three types regions:

1. Each $A$ region has either blanks or  $B$s below it and to the right, and it either has blanks or the board's edge above it and to the left. Its white squares are adjacent to their region's own marked black square, and free-and-clear across region boundaries to the right and down.
2. Repeat the preceding argument, swapping "$A$"/"$B$", "above"/"below", "top"/"bottom", and "left"/"right".
3. Each blank region has its white squares taken care of, either by the $A$ regions below it and to its right, or by the $B$ regions above it and to its left.

Before I started looking at it diagonally, I couldn't make heads or tails of it. The "row-major" process you describe does appear to generate the same result, although I don't immediately see why it should do that.

Comment: The row-major order means you get a marked black square in the upper left corner, followed by alternating blank and marked black squares along the top row. When we do the next row we are forced to leave every square unmarked (producing $A$ or blank regions) except (in the case $n\equiv 0 \pmod 4$) the last black square, which produces a $B$ region. After that, in each odd row we have to leave an unmarked black square beneath each $A$ or $B$ region and beneath any blank region to the right of a $B$ region,  ...

Comment: (continued) but each region just to the left of and below an $A$ region is below a blank region and therefore becomes an $A$, whereas in each even row we have unmarked cells until we get to the region below the last $A$ region, which must be marked as a $B$ region, and after that we are forced to mark alternating blank and $B$ regions.

Comment: In short, the classification of $2\times2$ regions in this answer seems to also be a good way to prove the row-major method as proposed in the question.

Comment: yes now i got it thanks. Thinking in terms of diagonals helped . And also the row major approach is exactly the same and will give the same selections. Thanks everyone